# Communication over wifi between 2 air apps. UDP? Socket? what do I need?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

any ideas on what I need to create a  touchscreen restaurant ordering system?

I've got the touch UI understood and implemented 100%.

What I can't figure out is how to implement the "Send order to 
kitchen" and "Call waiter" functions.

Each table will have a "client" computer running an air app. Calling the "Send order to kitchen" and "Call waiter" functions from the "client" computer should make the "client" communicate with a different "kitchen" computer over wifi.

I'm sure this can be done, I just don't know what I need.

I've read about UDP but I'm not sure that's it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore the UDP things you've read about. You want these to be _reliable_ messages and UDP cannot offer that. You can write a layer on top of UDP to try to make it reliable, but you'd just be implementing TCP again (and probably not as well).

Answer (score 1):

With real time data delivery, a streaming server is useful, like you mentioned. Adobe offers a free service for that:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

If you think dealing with that might be somewhat over your head, you can always use a standard, locally accessible web server like PHP/MySQL. It would even allow you to archive closed orders with say, an "order_status" database field in MySQL.

The host AIR application could periodically ping the server for "open" records and push an alert if it sees any new records. When an order goes out, you'd obviously send a separate request back to the web server to update a particular record as closed.

Additionally, clients would send their order requests to the web server for inserting new records into the database... with each new record receiving a unique id (primary key).

I personally would go for option 2 for the sake of a database implementation.

For an easy Windows PHP/MySQL installation: http://www.wampserver.com/

Comment: Great. Looks like the route I'll be taking. I was hoping to do this project all by myself in Air but I think I'll be needing another developer's help with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Don't over complicate it.

An AIR application can run a [ServerSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html) that other AIR apps can push and pull messages from. You only need to write and read [Sockets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html).

We even have cross-platform implementations of this, where either server or client is a native Android or iPhone app.

It works well as long as you can read / write servers and you are on the same network.

Good luck!

Juan